# Flutter / Dart Determine location

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I've been trying to get my location query more accurate for a while now. I use the following packages

import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

The location is retrieved, but it is far too inaccurate.

As a workaround, I have built in that Google Maps opens beforehand. There, the exact location is displayed and if I then perform the same query in the code, the location also fits better.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this without this Google workaround? I have also tried to set it to High or Best etc.. Unfortunately all that did nothing. Here is my code how I currently query the location.

```
Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
    bool hasInternet = await checkInternetConnectivity();
    setState(() {

      isLoading = true;
    });

    final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission(
        scaffoldMessengerKey);


    if (hasPermission == null || !hasPermission) return;


    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
      forceAndroidLocationManager: true,)
        .then((Position position) {
      _currentPosition = null;
      _currentAddress = null;
      setState(() => _currentPosition = position);


      if (hasInternet) {
        _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition!);
      } else {
        // Handle case without internet
      }



      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });


    }).catchError((e) {
      resetAll();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey Martin, this SO is English only :/ https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions